# How can I use page objects / application actions with cy.origin in cypress?

Tags: typescript, cypress

I'm trying to use page objects / application actions in my Cypress tests, with cy.origin. I'm new to cy.origin, but when not using cy.origin, I have code that looks a bit like:

my.test.cy.ts:

```
import { firstPageObjects } from '../some/file.po'
import { secondPageObjects } from '../other/file.po'

const fpo = new firstPageObjects()
const spo = new secondPageObects()

before (() => {
  // do something that should only happen once
})

describe ('what I am doing', () => {
  it ('tests something', () => {
    cy.visit('firsturl')
    fpo.this.click()
    fpo.that.type('foo')
   })

  it ('tests something else', () => {
    cy.visit('secondurl')
    spo.this.click(7)
    spo.that.type('bar')
   })

})
```

The problem with this is that my before block is called whenever the url changes, which I don't want. Using cy.origin stops this, but `fpo` and `spo` become undefined, and TBH I'm struggling to follow the cypress docs on cy.origin.

Can someone advise how to resolve this?

Many thanks

Comment: Is there a reason your `before()` is outside of your `describe()`? General best practice is for `before()` to be within a `describe()` or `context()` block, except for setting a global `before()`

Comment: No that's not best practice. Please read the docs at [/core-concepts/writing-and-organizing-tests#Support-file](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/writing-and-organizing-tests#Support-file)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't directly use page objects with `cy.origin()`.

There is a sandbox inside the `cy.origin()` callback function which prohibits the passing in of functions, or class instances (page objects), or anything else that cannot be serialized.

But you could try using `Cypress.require()` to get a new instance of the page object inside the `cy.origin()` callback, see [Dependencies / Sharing Code](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/origin#Dependencies--Sharing-Code)

Something like:

```js
cy.origin('cypress.io', () => {
  const FilePO = Cypress.require('../file.po')
  const filePO = new FilePO()

  // ... use the filePO instance
})
```

Comment: Weird, thought I had tried something like that.... clearly not EXACTLY like that though!! That's great, thanks @ingrid.tesch